# Javascript not working on pages, but the home page

Tags: javascript, html

I've just noticed that javascript elements aren't working correctly on the website. They are working, however, they only work on one page, and not site-wide.

http://www.radonsystems.net

Javascript elements, such as menu hovering, work on that page. Additionally, so does the jQuery fancybox [click on live chat].

No go to http://www.radonsystems.net/business/profile.2, notice that the menu hover and live chat fancybox doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like removing a script breaks it up. Have to split up the javascript in the header.